# How to develop a Proxy Server (TCP) for Android?

Tags: java, android, http, proxy, youtube

I am trying to develop a Proxy Server (TCP) in Android for YouTubeApp. I am going to use ProxyDroid (the phone is rooted), so that request/response goes through my Proxy Server. As its Android, I am using Java. But there are couple of challenges:

1. The request from the YouTubeApp has to be parsed. Is there is any existing library for parsing HTTP requests (in Java and can be used with Android)? Can anyone even suggest some snippets of code for this purpose? Or, do I have to do the parsing myself?
2. When requesting a remote site; e.g. www.google.com, do I have to use URL and openConnection()? Or, can sockets be used also? I am trying to find a way so that I can use sockets and get response from any site?

Hope to hear from u guys soon.